# How to Use Wowza Server for Native ios Application

Tags: objective-c, wowza

Is it possible to create a video chat application for IOS (Native Objective-C) using Wowza ?

How to send IOS camera and Microphone video/audio live stream to Wowza server ?

Is it possible to do chat with Wowza and IOS without using any RTMP library for IOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native Apple SDK receives and renders HLS, but it causes significant latency.  To implement a video chat client, you will need a 3rd party library to implement low latency streaming. Maybe look at nanocosmos.de

-jw

Comment: Hi @john  can you suggest some more 3rd party library to implement low latency streaming.

Comment: hi @john from wowza  nanocosmos.de is too much costly . can you suggest  other option for the same. i hope any other 3rd party streaming will be available. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza accepts input stream as RTSP, RTMP, or MPEG-TS so you need a library that is able to use any of these protocol.

To play the stream from wowza you can use HLS that is native in IOS and I assume it will be easier (I do not have experience with native application in IOS)

Check the technical specs of wowza for futher information.
[https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine/specifications]